# How to modify an object after axios get request is resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, es6-promise

I am setting the res.data of an object `containerInfo` in Vue afer making an axios get request, like so:

```
methods: {
    searchContainers(containerSearch) {
      this.containerQuery = JSON.parse(containerSearch.container_query)[0];
      this.imageBranch = JSON.parse(containerSearch.container_query)[1];
      this.containerInfo["image_branch"] = this.imageBranch
      this.url = this.containerQuery.split('/');

      axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/get?name=${this.url[0]}/${this.url[1]}/${this.url[2]}&ver=${this.url[3]}`)
        .then(res => this.containerInfo = res.data)
        .then(this.containerInfo = [...this.containerInfo, this.imageBranch]);

    }
```

I want to add `this.imageBranch` to the `containerInfo` object after the data object is received/set in vue.

The issue is that the axios res, once received (takes a few secs), deletes the `this.imageBranch` key/value added. I know I should probably add it after the promise is resolved but I can't figure out how.

Can someone please help!

Comment: you need to pass a function to `.then` ... anything else is ignored (see how your second `.then` is not being passed a function)

Comment: Can you please provide an example @Bravo?

Comment: the first `.then` has a function passed as the argument, the second, doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two `.then`, use only one and execute all your code inside the arrow function, like this:

```
methods: {
    searchContainers(containerSearch) {
        this.containerQuery = JSON.parse(containerSearch.container_query)[0];
        this.imageBranch = JSON.parse(containerSearch.container_query)[1];
        this.containerInfo["image_branch"] = this.imageBranch
        this.url = this.containerQuery.split('/');

        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/get?name=${this.url[0]}/${this.url[1]}/${this.url[2]}&ver=${this.url[3]}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.containerInfo = res.data;
                this.containerInfo = [...this.containerInfo, this.imageBranch]
            });

    }
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but still received the same result :(

Comment: @swarr35 - depends on where you are inspecting `this.containerInfo`

Comment: I have tried all of the above suggestions. My `this.imageBranch` keeps getting deleted though once the res is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using await/async syntax which is clear and straightforward. So the codes should be like this

```
async searchContainers() {
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/get?name=${this.url[0]}/${this.url[1]}/${this.url[2]}&ver=${this.url[3]}`);
  this.containerInfo = res.data;
  this.containerInfo = [...this.containerInfo, this.imageBranch];
}
```

Comment: why not just `this.containerInfo = [...this.res.data, this.imageBranch];`

Comment: I am continuing to get the same result even with the await/async syntax

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Needed to set a key in object as such: `this.containerInfo.image_branch = this.imageBranch`